# Apache Spark Failed to connect to master localhost:7077

Tags: apache-spark, port, master-slave

I am very new to Apache Spark and trying to run spark on my local machine.
First I tried to start the master using the following command:

```
./sbin/start-master.sh
```

Which got successfully started. And then I tried to start the worker using

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker  spark://localhost:7077 -c 1 -m 512M
```

which eventually failed with the following log:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/06/09 17:01:58 INFO Worker: Started daemon with process name: 9301@sumit-Inspiron-5537
17/06/09 17:01:58 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
17/06/09 17:01:58 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
17/06/09 17:01:58 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
17/06/09 17:01:58 WARN Utils: Your hostname, sumit-Inspiron-5537 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.1.16 instead (on interface wlp2s0)
17/06/09 17:01:58 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
17/06/09 17:01:59 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/06/09 17:01:59 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: sumit
17/06/09 17:01:59 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: sumit
17/06/09 17:01:59 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/06/09 17:01:59 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/06/09 17:01:59 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(sumit); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(sumit); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/06/09 17:01:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 35827.
17/06/09 17:02:00 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker 192.168.1.16:35827 with 1 cores, 512.0 MB RAM
17/06/09 17:02:00 INFO Worker: Running Spark version 2.1.1
17/06/09 17:02:00 INFO Worker: Spark home: /home/sumit/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7
17/06/09 17:02:00 WARN Utils: Service 'WorkerUI' could not bind on port 8081. Attempting port 8082.
17/06/09 17:02:00 WARN Utils: Service 'WorkerUI' could not bind on port 8082. Attempting port 8083.
17/06/09 17:02:00 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8083.
17/06/09 17:02:00 INFO WorkerWebUI: Bound WorkerWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.1.16:8083
17/06/09 17:02:00 INFO Worker: Connecting to master localhost:7077...
17/06/09 17:02:00 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master localhost:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$Worker$$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:218)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7077
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:7077
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:640)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    ... 1 more
```

This has gone into attempts loop. I had checked localhost on 8080 and Master is working properly. Please suggest what can be done in this situation to get the slave up and working, because only then the spark job can be run. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason for trying to have a master and slave on your local machine rather than using the built in local deploy mode? I suspect you may be making this process harder on yourself than it needs to be ;)